# Saving scanned barcode data to txt file

Tags: android, string, textview

I need help with saving my scanned barcode data to one txt file ( I know you would recommend me to save it via SharedPreferences but i need it to be simple) 
So basically when i scan code its data should be saved in txt file on my phone. Here is code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button scanBtn;
    private TextView formatTxt, contentTxt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        scanBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
        formatTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_format);
        contentTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_content);
        scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v){
        if(v.getId()==R.id.scan_button){
            IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
            scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
        }
    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
            formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: "+scanFormat);
            contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: "+scanContent);
        }
        else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("data.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(scanContent);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
```

**UPDATE**:

Other way, with the possible to write to sdcard

```
try {
            File myFile = new File("/sdcard/data.txt");
            myFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                    new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.append(scanContent);
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();
            Toast.makeText(yourActivity.this,
                    "File created'mysdfile.txt'",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(yourActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Don't Forget to add permision:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151304/discussion-on-answer-by-bruno-ferreira-saving-scanned-barcode-data-to-txt-file).